# No qualifying bean of type in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Currently I'm facing an issue in Autowire configuration between controller and the service layer.

**Log**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ults.hrms.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController extends ConvertReqDataToJSON {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppController.class);

    /* creating bean definition in Spring container(DI) */

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/listuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Employe> listUsers() throws Exception {

        return employeService.findAllUsers();
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService extends GenericDaoImpl<Employe>{

    public List<Employe> findAllUsers() throws Exception {
        return findAllUsers();
    }
}
GenericDao

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public T findAll() throws Exception{
        Criteria criteria =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(getEntityClass()).addOrder(Order.asc("firstName"));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        return (T) criteria.list();
    }
}
```

Autowiring doesnt work for some reason... "`No qualifying bean of type com.ults.hrms.service.EmployeeService`.

I've tried with different combinations of `@Component` and `@Transactional` too.

Sorry for a lot of code, but I don't know what can cause that error anymore.

Comment: why the service is extending DAO? that looks weird

Comment: It is a Generic dao that why am extending.its wrong  or not?

Comment: you are not supposed to do it in Service layer

Comment: what is the solution for that

Comment: you have logical errors... you have to separate your code into logical layers. as @Jobin said it's strange your service to extend your dao. Give me your config file for beans discovery. (@Configuration or *.xml file) don't what is your env.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of `No qualifying bean of type [com.ults.hrms.service.EmployeeService]` is that the autowired property name is not correct..

change

```
@Autowired
EmployeeService employeService;
```

to

```
@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService ;
```

Comment: You dont need that extends dao in service layer

Answer (score 0):

You can  do like this

```
@Service("employeService")
public class EmployeeService extends GenericDaoImpl<Employe>{

    public List<Employe> findAllUsers() throws Exception {
        return findAllUsers();
    }
}
```

@Service***("employeService")*** this allows you to choose the name you are going to use while autowiring